# Nominatim europe import

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I've looked at previous posts on this topic but couldn't understand why the import process died. Therefore I cannot start it again until I understand what the errors in the log mean. (import took 12 days)

here's the famous nominatim setup log

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TYPE
Import
osm2pgsql version 0.93.0-dev (64 bit id space)

Using projection SRS 4326 (Latlong)
NOTICE:  table "place" does not exist, skipping
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=2800MB, maxblocks=44800*65536, allocation method=11
Mid: loading persistent node cache from /srv/nominatim/data/flatnode.file
Mid: pgsql, cache=2800
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

Reading in file: /srv/nominatim/data/europe-latest.osm.pbf
Using PBF parser.
Processing: Node(1916319k 644.1k/s) Way(234287k 0.25k/s) Relation(3519490 21.55/s)  parse time: 1109177s
Node stats: total(1916319008), max(4937556462) in 2975s
Way stats: total(234287257), max(503447033) in 942887s
Relation stats: total(3519494), max(7358761) in 163315s
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

Going over pending ways...
        0 ways are pending

Using 1 helper-processes
Finished processing 0 ways in 0 s


Going over pending relations...
        0 relations are pending

Using 1 helper-processes
Finished processing 0 relations in 0 s

Stopping table: planet_osm_nodes
Stopped table: planet_osm_nodes in 0s
Stopping table: planet_osm_ways
Stopped table: planet_osm_ways in 0s
Stopping table: planet_osm_rels
Building index on table: planet_osm_rels
ERROR: Error executing external command: /srv/nominatim/Nominatim/build/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql --flat-nodes /srv/nominatim/data/flatnode.file -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore --number-processes 1 -C 2800 -P 5432 -d nominatim /srv/nominatim/data/europe-latest.osm.pbf
Error executing external command: /srv/nominatim/Nominatim/build/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql --flat-nodes /srv/nominatim/data/flatnode.file -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore --number-processes 1 -C 2800 -P 5432 -d nominatim /srv/nominatim/data/europe-latest.osm.pbf
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check dmesg for OOM entries? Maybe your system run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks @scai, I just learned about dmesg and after running ````dmesg -T | grep 'out of memory'```` I found out that indeed, the process run out of memory and that's why it died